# Drupal Scald: Resize image in wysiwyg text area

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I looked for during several days the solution but i didn't found.
My problem:
I drop an atom (image) onto a wysiwyg (CKeditor) text area (body).
I want to resize this image. So i click on the ckeditor image icon, change the width and height properties.
I saved my article. But the image stay with the original size.

I tried to change the atom context and transcoders, but it is not exactly that i want.
I want to change the image size dynamicly in a wysiwyg text area.

Do you have a solution of my issue?
Thanks.

Drupal 7
Scald 7.x-1.1
Wysiwyg 7.x-2.2
CKeditor 4.3.1

Comment: When you say the image stays the same size, do you mean the height and width attributes do not get rendered in the HTML output? Or do you mean the image is not transcoded?

Comment: Yes, I mean the height and width attributes.

Comment: After you adjust the height/width in CKEditor, can you click the editor's "View HTML" button and see if it's setting the height/width attributes directly, or using a style="" attribute? The input format is probably stripping off some attributes, and if you switch it to a more allowable input format, it should stop doing that.

Comment: It setting the style="" attribute. You can see the HTML code in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

@drnugent The source code in ckeditor is : 
`<div class="dnd-atom-wrapper type-image context-sdl_editor_representation atom-align-center" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="dnd-drop-wrapper">
    <!-- scald=4:sdl_editor_representation {"link":""} -->
        <div class="image">
            <img alt="" src="http://.../xxx.jpg" style="height:100px; width:200px">
        </div>
    <!-- END scald=4 -->
    </div>
</div>`.

But in the database it is : 
`<div class="dnd-atom-wrapper type-image context-sdl_editor_representation atom-align-center" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="dnd-drop-wrapper">
    [scald=4:sdl_editor_representation {"link":""}]
    </div>
</div>`.

The height and width is not save. After the HTML output is rendered by the atom context (here it's editor representation): 
`<div  class="dnd-drop-wrapper">
<div class="image">
<img width="182" height="71" alt="" src="http://.../xxx.jpg" class="image-style-none" typeof="foaf:Image">
</di>
</di>`